# I can't display the image in django admin UI

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh8IL.png)

my UI interface keep showing this url img source, meanwhile what i want is the image preview.
maybe i need some additional format?
what is the html tag needed to show as image in browser view?

```
this is my source code now for **admin.py**
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Categorie, Product
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(Categorie)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('category_name',)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('category',)
    list_display = ('product_name', 'category','thumbnail_preview','description')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.category_id = obj.category.id
        obj.save()

    def thumbnail_preview(self, obj):
        preview_html = ''
        for i in range(1, 6):
            product_photo_field = f'Photo_{i}'
            if hasattr(obj, product_photo_field):
                product_photo = getattr(obj, product_photo_field)
                if product_photo:
                    preview_html += format_html('<img src="{}" style="max-height:100px; max-width:100px;" />', product_photo.url)
                    print(preview_html)
        if not preview_html:
            return '(No Images)'
        return preview_html
    
    thumbnail_preview.allow_tags = True
    thumbnail_preview.short_description = 'Product Photos'
```

and this is the **models.py** file

```
from django.db import models

**# Model for Category**
class Categorie(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

**# Model for Product**
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photos/')
    Photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    Photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    Photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    Photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

**# Function to create initial categories**
def create_initial_categories(sender, **kwargs):
    categories = ['Lantai', 'Atap', 'Bangunan']
    for category in categories:
        Categorie.objects.get_or_create(category_name=category)

**# Signal to create initial categories after migrations**
models.signals.post_migrate.connect(create_initial_categories, sender=models)
```

anyone can help me solve this endless problem?